# Views data export remove tags from xml output

Tags: views, importing-exporting

I want to remove `<no-name>` tag generated by views data export on xml output
Any ideas please?

I have already tried to override template output for the field but no results :(

Answer (score 1):

I have found the problem, i was overriding the template but with a the wrong code, i was using the alternative style template with these variables:

```
<?php print $header ?>
<?php print $body ?>
<?php print $footer ?>
```

Instead these should be used :

```
// Short tags act bad below in the html so we print it here.
print '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>';
?>

<<?php print $root_node; ?>>

<?php
/**
 * @file views-view-table.tpl.php
 * Template to display a view as a table.
 *
 * - $title : The title of this group of rows.  May be empty.
 * - $rows: An array of row items. Each row is an array of content
 *   keyed by field ID.
 * - $header: an array of headers(labels) for fields.
 * - $themed_rows: a array of rows with themed fields.
 * @ingroup views_templates
 */
?>
<?php foreach ($themed_rows as $count => $row): ?>
  <<?php print $item_node; ?>>
<?php foreach ($row as $field => $content): ?>
    <<?php print $xml_tag[$field]; ?>><?php print $content; ?></<?php print $xml_tag[$field]; ?>>
<?php endforeach; ?>
  </<?php print $item_node; ?>>
<?php endforeach; ?>

</<?php print $root_node; ?>>
```

I'm posting so maybe it will be helpful for someone else.